# How to call two animations without them interfering with each other?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've made a hint box that slides up with an animation, but i also want to -10 coins when the user taps on a candle button so I created a series of photos that make an animation which depicts -10 to the user...

the problem is that every time the candle button is pressed the -10coins animation overrides the hint sliding box and replaces it, thus making it impossible for the user to find a hint again...

Code:

```
- (IBAction)firstHintq:(id)sender {
[_hintView setHidden:NO];
[_hintViewTwo setHidden:YES];
[_hintViewThree setHidden:YES];
_hintView.text = @"Ηταν η τεταρτη τηλεφωνικη εταιρια στην Ελλαδα";
//connected to global BOOL
if (!btn1Pressed) {
    if((coins -10) >= 0){
        coins = coins -10;
        score = score -2;

      // Load images starts
NSArray *imageNames = @[ @"coin-10-1.png", @"coin-10-2.png",
                         @"coin-10-3.png", @"coin-10-4.png", @"coin-10-5.png", @"coin-10-6.png",
                         @"coin-10-7.png", @"coin-10-8.png", @"coin-10-9.png", @"coin-10-10.png", @"coin-10-11.png",@"coin-10-12.png", @"coin-10-13.png",@"coin-10-14.png",@"coin-10-15.png"];

NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++) {
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
}

// Normal Animation
UIImageView *animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 200, 30, 70)];
animationImageView.animationImages = images;
animationImageView.animationDuration = 1.5;
animationImageView.animationRepeatCount = 10;

[self.view addSubview:animationImageView];
[animationImageView startAnimating];

//coin animation ends


        //changes image
        [_candleone setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"candle2_03.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.candletwo.hidden = NO;
        //Animates the 2nd candle
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

CGPoint center = [_candletwo center];
center.x = 88;
center.y = 70;
[_candletwo setCenter:center];
[UIView commitAnimations];
        //sets the global BOOL as true
        coinsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",coins];
        btn1Pressed = true;

    }
    else{
         [_hintView setHidden:YES];
        //Show an alert that the user has not enough coins
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TITLE" message:@"MESSAGE" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"RETURN BUTTON" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

}
```

How to fix this issue, so that both animations activate properly?

Answer (score 0):

For animations better use:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:time // time is a double
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^() {
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                 }];
```

Then you can use 2 `animateWithDuration: delay: options: completion:`

And OFC, you can nest 2:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:time // time is a double
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^() {
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     [UIView animateWithDuration:time // time is a double
                                           delay:0.0f
                                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                                      animations:^() {
                                      }
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                      }];
                 }];
```

Comment: It still overrides maybe I sould change some values from you code, idk?

Comment: @Gabriel.Messana It still overrides maybe I sould change some values from you code, idk?

Comment: @Jelter Maybe you have a problem of layouts. Maybe the -10coins animation remains in the middle of your View just over the candle?